# How to best split a preferences view into tabs in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails application the `show` and `edit` views of my `preferences` have grown to contain about 20 or so attributes.

This is not very user-friendly since the user has to scroll to see all his preference options.

So I would like to subdivide all the attributes into tabs labelled `time`, `formatting`, and `general`.

What is the *Rails way* of doing that?

What I have in mind is filtering the views with a GET variable à la `http://localhost:3000/preferences?tab=general`

But will I be able to redirect to that same tab again after the user hit `update`? How would that have to be done?

I also wonder if `validation` will work using this approach.

I had a look at the [RailsCast about Multistep Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms) already but in my case I don't need "steps" of any sort. The user should be able to select the tabs in random order.

I also don't want to use any gems. I prefer to hack something together myself.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: what about creating a spearate actions with index link ? and then customize each action about what the data should appear , and make a separate page for each action

Comment: Personally I would look at a front end solution to this problem.  Using CSS styling and something like jQuery to avoid unnecessarily creating multiple new views.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery-ui to implement the tab view so that you can design which tab to show by javascript. You can add an if statement for each validation to indicate when will that validation will be take effect.

Answer (score 0):

In your `edit` view add the `tab` parameter value as a hidden field to the form.  It will then be passed to the `update` action and your controller can make a redirect decision there.